# React native - How to get file info when user select pdf file with our application form storage "open with" option?

Tags: android, react-native, pdf

I am working on a pdf viewer app, where I show pdf content. Everything is working fine when the user selects a file from the app.

but i also want to handle a case where the user selects a file from storage and try open with my app from "open with app list".

when the user clicks on my app from apps listed in open with the option. how can I get file info?[image]

Comment: What do you consider to be file info? You should use content resolver to query the obtained uri -the content provider of it- for all kind of info.